# Java inheritance issue while using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, list, inheritance, jaxb

Say my parent class is storing my `LinkedList` which 3 different child cast will have access to for their own collection

example

```
class A {
    LL<A>list
}

class b extends A

class c extends A
```

They all have collection of `B`s and `C`s .

When I tried marshaling `B` it said `a` cannot be cast `b`
and on the xml field in only showed attributes of `a` none of `b`.

Comment: Do you generate the JAXB classes from a XSD? Can you show us the relevant part of the XSD? And can you provide us the exact error message (with the stack trace if possible)?

Comment: @Puce

Code Example

class Records{
LL<Record> r = new LL<Record>();
//some other function
}

class Employees extends Record{
//functions to make use of LL from parent storing multiple Employee
}

now when i tried marshalling it, it only recognise the object as a record hence only keeping the Record attribute but none of the Employee attribute.

Comment: Please try to answer my questions. Otherwise it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: Or in other words: the code you have shown us so far cannot be marshalled at all, as the JAXB annotations are missing. IMHO in most situations the best way is to start with the XSD and then generate the JAXB classes.